# Running Installer or Uninstaller fails with SWbemObjectSet: Invalid Class

Tags: windows, installation, uninstall

Whenever I try to uninstall a piece of software through Add/Remove Programs I get the `SWbemObjectSet: Invalid Class` error. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the software installation process has been interrupted, resulting in corrupted entries in WMI repository.

- Press Windows+Q and type "cmd" into the search bar that pops up.
- Right-click on Command Prompt and select Run as Administrator
- Type the following into the command prompt, then press enter.

  ```
  net stop winmgmt
  ```
- When prompted if you wish to continue, type Y and press enter.
  Type the following into the command prompt and press enter.

  ```
  winmgmt /resetrepository
  ```
- Restart your computer.